# Referencing Metadata in SAM Template (YAML)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

How I can reference "Metadata Name" on SAM Template (YAML).
I try to use Fn::Sub: config/${Metadata.Name} as below but I got validation error.
Can anyone help?
Or is it possible to get 'stack name' in the cloudformation in the template.yaml?

```
Metadata:
  AWS::ServerlessRepo::Application:
    Name: My-Serverless
    Description: My Serverless
    SemanticVersion: 1.0.0
Resources:
  ConfigurationParameter:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: config/${Metadata.Name}
      Type: String
      Value: false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NAME: !Sub config/${Fn::GetMetadata: MyResource|Name}
```